# Performance difference at stack (re)creating?

Tags: c++, stack

is there a Performance difference between this:

```
int test;
void Update()
{
    test +=2;
}
```

and this:

```
void Update()
{
    int test;
    test +=2;
}
```

--

```
int main()
{
    while(true)
        Update();
}
```

I ask because the second Code is better to read (you don't need to declare it at Class headers), so i would use it if the performance is not lower.

Comment: Your tests are not congruent because the scope of test dictates the meaning of what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is highly unlikely that there is a performance difference between the two snippets only profiling your code can tell reliably but there is a important functional difference tha you should consider here.

If your `test` variable is needed only inside the function `update()` then you **must** declare it inside the function. That way the variable has a limited scope inside the function.The lifetime of such a local variable is limited to the scope where it resides.i.e. Within the function body, till the closing brace`}`.

If at all you want your `test` variable to maintain state across function calls then it can be a local static variable declared inside the function.

Declaring `test` outside the function makes it an global variable. And it can be accessible in any function in the same file.Also being a global variable it lifetime extends till end of program.

Comment: Thank you, i knew about the functional difference, i choosed a bad example ;)

Btw, if i use static int; in a function, is this then also static across instances of classes?

Comment: @Sapd: A `static int` variable declared inside a function will be shared across all the calls that are made to the function.Yes, it will be maintained across all instances of classes.

Answer (score 0):

Performance difference, unlikely. This is simple to test, but depends on your compiler. Check the output assembly and do some benchmarking. If there is a difference, it's likely to be tiny.

However, there is a major functional difference. The second example is effectively useless, as `test` will be reset every `Update`. To avoid that, you could declare it as `static int test`, but you've essentially written the first example again.

So, they are very different things, but will have similar performance.